# how to set variable name(attribute) in xsl:element

Tags: visual-studio, xslt, xslt-2.0

i have this code that purpose of that create dynamic elment name.

```
 <xsl:template  name="Band" match="*[contains(name(), 'Band')]">
    <xsl:param name="DA" />
    <xsl:element name="$DA"> <!--error this-->

    </xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add curly braces to evaluate the variable:

```
<xsl:param name="DA" />
<xsl:element name="{$DA}">
  ...
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: Just to add, that syntax is called "attribute value template": http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates